# inode number in different filesystems

Tags: filesystems, inode

If I mount directory A(have a file file_a in it) to directory B, the two directories are in different filesystems, will file_a in the two directories share the same inode number?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the inode number of the file will be that of the source directory A. Any new file created in directory B will follow the conventions of the file system in which directory A is present.In Linux terminology,what you're doing is essentially a `bind mount`.